# DevOpts tools for WMQ

Tags: deployment, ibm-mq

I need a devOpts deployments tool that can do the following tasks:

1. Creating a project that can contain different queues or artifacts within a GUI application
2. Create Queues and artifacts via a GUI accessible to non WMQ experts within the DEV environment only (without relying on a script)
3. Once tested properly, having the tool deploy the project (more specifically the queues contained in the project) from DEV to INT via a GUI that is only accessible by the Deployment team

Does anyone have any suggestions of tools that can perform this other than using scripts

(I have heard mixed reviews about IBM uDeploy, that configurations can not be reused, etc)

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of 3rd party MQ Administration/Configuration tools available for IBM MQ.  You can find a list of them [**here**](http://capitalware.com/mq_tools_comm.html#mqadmin).